# Input requested on localization setup for DB

Tags: sql-server

I am building an ASP.Net site that will pull dynamic data from SQL server. The site will be built with localization/globalization foundations in anticipation that in a year or so the site will start holding translations for non-English speaking users. I already know how accomplish this in ASP.Net for the static content but I would like some suggestions on a DB design for the dynamic data. I have toyed with the following 3 ideas and would like some input on them and any thoughts on other ways.

1. Create a unique database for each language set and use ASP.Net to dynamically change which DB the data comes from.
2. Create copies of each table appending the local code to hold the translated data (i.e. Table-en, Table-fr, Table1-en, Table1-fr)
3. Leave DB and table design intact (only adding a single column to hold the local code) and insert translated data as a new row entry.

Comment: Is the data in the database going to be user-editable, or will it be totally static?

Comment: The data will be editable by select users given permision to do so but the general visitor will not be able to do so.

Comment: Can you please re-post the question I removed at your request, so that the original answerer can re-post their answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up going with a dual table design. The first table would contain all data that would not have a translation for it. A second table would have the word "Translation" appended to it and it would contain columns to cover all the data needing translations and have a single translation per row.